# My tablet does not log into my Aviation Stack Exchange account

Tags: support, login

I have been a member of [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour) Stack Exchange for 4 years, using the same account.  Recently I joined [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) Stack Exchange and now my tablet does not open my Aviation Stack Exchange, or [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour) Stack Exchange accounts.

Usually, joining a new Stack Exchange site just adds to existing accounts.

What has gone wrong here?

Comment: It looks as if you ended up with two accounts https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/126843/robert-digiovanni and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/126844/robert-digiovanni

Comment: I wouldn't put your email address here, it's crawled by all sorts who likely might spam you or sell your details to.... who knows. Could you tell us how you normally log-in, is it through the stackexchange.com profile? Do you use a password manager or other? What browser are you using (version too), is privacy-mode engaged?

Comment: One of your accounts, as pointed out by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, is an unregistered one. Use the contact us link at the bottom of every page to request the two accounts be merged.

Comment: Thanks so much, normally log-in is only required once (for example with Aviation Stack Exchange) and the tablet remembers it.  I will merge the 2 Chem accounts and see if that helps.